# Logos in transactional emails are different

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

In one email i have the logo like:
http://myshop.com/skin/frontend/mytemplate/default/images/logo_email.gif

In the other email I have the logo like:
http://myshop.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/logo_email.gif

In both templates the same code is used to include the logo:

```
<img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/>
```

Where could it be defined that in one email it takes the right logo but in the other it take the logo out of skin/adminhtml ?

Comment: the url, which provided by you are not found. Check once and update

Answer (score 1):

Logo's for emails can be set in

```
System > Configuration > General > Design > Transactional Emails
```

By default the email logo's that you upload there are stored in

```
[your Magento install dir]/media/email/logo/default/
```

If you want to use only one logo, make sure that you have selected the same active logo for each store view. So check the logo settings for each store view under `Current Configuration Scope` at the top of the left sidebar.

> **NOTE:** If you choose to use a different email logo for each store view then those email logo's will be stored in
>
> ```
> [your Magento install dir]/media/email/logo/stores/StoreID/
> ```